# How to pass variable value between identical instances of WindowsForm

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio

I have a base form `From1`. In the form when button is clicked, new form `From2` is created.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
}
```

User can create several instances of `From2`. In `From2` user can set a value in textBox and click a button. Once it is clicked, value from textBox has to be somehow transferred to all other created instances of `From2`. How can I do that?

Comment: Add a constructor which takes a string and pass the value...or add a property.  There are many, many such posts here showing how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: remember all forms you created.

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    allForms.Add(f2);          // remember it
    f2.Show();        
}
```

Step 2: when the value changes, update all remembered forms

```cs
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Form2 form in allForms)
    {
        form.MyValue = textbox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Just write the code like that, then let the IDE help you creating the properties and adjust the visibility accordingly, e.g. have the IDE help you implement a property in Form2 that sets the text

```cs
string MyValue 
{
    set
    {
        anotherTextbox.Text = value;
    }
}
```

You'll then notice that you need some more stuff, probably.

Step 3: remove the form from the list when it is closed.

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    allForms.Add(f2);
    f2.Closed += OnClose;   // Method to be called when form is closed
    f2.Show();        
}

private void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form = (Form2) sender;
    form.Closed -= OnClose;   // Unregister event handler
    allForms.Remove(form);    // remove it
}
```

Comment: I've never had such an issue with an answer not updating like that. I see it now.

Comment: You don't even need to keep track of allForms yourself, you can also use `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().ToArray()` to retrieve the list of open forms.

Comment: @Dwedit: yes. That's sort of "magic" that happens under the hoods which I don't recommend for beginners. Let them first be explicit about what they are doing so they can understand what they wrote themselves, before requiring a lot of knowlegde what code someone else (Microsoft) wrote.